# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instancemethod found in django templates

Tags: django, unicode, django-templates

I have a django app with version 1.2.4 and updated to 1.6.5, and i have changed a lot of url structure from `{% url name %}` to `{% url 'name' %}` but at one place it was causing me the below

**Traceback**

```
File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/proj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  278.                     lookup_str = callback.__module__ + "." + callback.__name__

Exception Type: TypeError at /store/
Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instancemethod found
```

**template code that causing error**

```
<ul id="product-tabs">
    <li class="passive"><span><a href={% url "webstore_new" passive_year %}>{{ passive_year }}</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href={% url "webstore_new" active_year %}>{{ active_year }}</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

So what was wrong in the url tag in the above template code ?

**Edit**

**views.py**

```
def products(request, year=None):
  current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
  present_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
  if Products.objects.filter(year__contains = present_year+1):
    active_year = present_year + 1
    passive_year = present_year
  else:
    active_year = present_year
    passive_year = present_year - 1

    products = Products.objects.filter(Q(site=current_site, year=year))
  .....
  ......
  .......      
  variables = {
    'obj': products,
    'active_year': active_year,
    'passive_year': passive_year,
  }

  response = RequestContext(request, variables)
  return render_to_response('new/store/webstore.html', response)
```

Comment: Can you please also show your views.py ? Function which renders this template?

Comment: @Silwestpl :ok pasted the view above

Comment: @Silwestpl :Actually not only above but also i am getting the same error when trying to hit/access the admin(localhost:8000/admin/) url

Comment: What is the line with `webstore_new` in `urls.py`?

Comment: @Selcuk :It is the name(name=webstore_new) of the url given in urls.py